# i want to ask question about django project . I am working on django project an E commerce website

Tags: django-forms

"I have been experiencing an issue with my sign-up and login forms not displaying on my webpage. I have thoroughly reviewed the code logic, and it appears to be correct to me. I've been struggling with this problem for several days, and despite my efforts, I have not been able to resolve it.

I suspect there may be an underlying issue that I'm missing. Since I don't have access to a teacher or mentor, I'm seeking assistance from the Stack Overflow community.

Would it be possible for someone to review my code and help me identify the problem? I'm happy to provide the code details if necessary. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!"